# Why does the 'i' need to be divided by 2 in caculating positional encoding?

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

In this transformer tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer

```
def get_angles(pos, i, d_model):
  angle_rates = 1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i//2)) / np.float32(d_model))
  return pos * angle_rates
```

I don't understand why 'i//2' is used, since in the original formula there is no specification of the integer division.

So what's the purpose of i//2?

Answer (score 0):

according to the formula

> PE(pos, 2i) = sin(1/100000^(2i /D) , PE(pos, 2i+1) = cos(1/100000^(2i
> /D)

As you can see, for odd row, 2i -> 2i, for even row 2i+1 -> 2i, for example, a word embedding with [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] should transfer to [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3], there is where i//2 comes from.